# How is it possible to get data from one form that has multiple textareas in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to get data from one form that has multiple textareas inside , In my views: 'compare_ingredients' I've tried requesting data from my form id 'compareform' also the textarea id 'ingredients', but when I enter something into one texture and click on submit it comes back as 'None' when I print. Here is my html and views:

html :

```
<div class="container-fluid">



        <h4>Please enter in your ingredients:</h4>

        <h6>(Seperate each item by comma)</h6>

        <br>

        <button class="add_item">Add Item</button>
        <br>

            

            <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 mx-auto">
                            
                            
                    <form action="{% url 'compare_ingredients' %}" method="POST" name="compareform" id="compare">
                            {% csrf_token %}

                            <br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info sub_btn">Submit</button>
                            

                            
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary back_button">
                            <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="back_button_text">Back</a>
                            </button>
                            <br>


                            <br>
                            <div class="row form_row">
                                    <div class="col mb-4">
                                        <h5>Item 1</h5>
                                        <div class="card form_card">
                                            <div class="card-body compare_cardbody">
                                                <textarea name="ingredients1" id="ingredients" cols="30" rows="10" form="compareform"></textarea>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </div>    
                                    </div>
                                
                                    
                              
                                    <div class="col mb-4">
                                        <h5>Item 2</h5>
                                        <div class="card form_card">
                                            <div class="card-body compare_cardbody">
                                                <textarea name="ingredients2" id="ingredients" cols="30" rows="10" form="compareform"></textarea>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </div>    
                                    </div>
                            </div>    
                                
                                                       
                    </form>
     
                
            </div>
 
                            
      
        
        
    </div>
```

views.py:

```
def compare_ingredients(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        ingredients = request.POST.get('compareform')

        print(ingredients)
        
    
    return render(request, 'result/compare.html')
```

Comment: ingredients = request.POST.get('ingredients1') should work

Comment: I've tried that but when I try printing ingredients it says None

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured it out , the problem was in the html textarea I had the name of the form as 'compareform' when it should have been 'compare' :

```
<textarea name="ingredients2" id="ingredients" cols="30" rows="10" form="compare"></textarea>
```

then in my views I did:

```
ingredients1 = request.POST.get('ingredients1')
```